# How do I make animation finish and can't be interrupted even when I let go?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Basically I want the roll animation to play completely, and not be interrupted like a fighting game special move. So when I press down or, hold down in this case, the animation has to complete one cycle, and then I have to press or hold the down key again for it to start up again.  Any help would be amazing.

```
    const int STATE_Idle = 0;
    const int STATE_Run = 1;
    const int STATE_Roll = 2;
    const int STATE_Jump = 3;



if (Input.GetKey ("down") 
        {

            changeState(STATE_Roll);
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(1f, -.4f, 0f) * rollSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("roll"))
            _isPlaying_roll = true;
        else
            _isPlaying_roll = false;

    }

    //--------------------------------------
    // Change the players animation state
    //--------------------------------------
    void changeState(int state){

        if (_currentAnimationState == state)
            return;

        switch (state) {

        case STATE_Run:
            animator.SetInteger ("state", STATE_Run);
            break;

        case STATE_Roll:
            animator.SetInteger ("state", STATE_Roll);
            break;

        case STATE_Jump:
            animator.SetInteger ("state", STATE_Jump);
            break;

        case STATE_Idle:
            animator.SetInteger ("state", STATE_Idle);
            break;

        }

        _currentAnimationState = state;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of program is this? Web Forms?

Comment: I'm using unity 5, mono

Comment: Is that [tag:unity3d]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you place your animation strip on a list. Every time you want the animation to run, check for any other user input that isn't the one you want. If it's the input you want, iterate through the whole list then continue doing whatever else was next.

Something like this:

```
foreach(var strip in animationStrips)
{
    //Display current strip
}
```

Comment: How do I make sure it finishes completely? Using unity 5 monodevelop.

Comment: Well I don't have any experience with unity but in c# just iterate till you hit the last index. I'm updated my suggestion with an example.

Comment: An iteration will loop till the end on it's own, don't worry about that. You can, of course, force it to stop anytime you want. Maybe this helps http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/AnimationSection.html

Comment: I will look into and try this asap.